# A question about a well known problem from the K&R book

Tags: c

Hello to all and all my wishes for the upcoming New Year!

A, perhaps naive, question. Bellow is my solution to the K&R exercise 1-12:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    long ch;

    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (ch != ' ' && ch != '\n' && ch != '\t') {
            while (ch != ' ' && ch != '\n' && ch != '\t' && ch != EOF) {
                putchar(ch);
                ch = getchar();
            }
            putchar('\n');
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Which works as expected (and ignores many consecutive blanks/tabs). My question is that, if I follow the advice on (the beginning of) page 17 and modify the piece of code as:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    long ch;

    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (ch != ' ' && ch != '\n' && ch != '\t') {
            while ((ch = getchar()) != ' ' && (ch = getchar()) != '\n' && (ch = getchar()) != '\t' && (ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
                putchar(ch);
            }
            putchar('\n');
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

it does **not** work! Why?

Comment: *"...if I follow the advice on (the beginning of) page 17..."* ***What*** advice? Quote it for the people who don't have a K&R lying around. But the answer is: Because you're repeatedly calling the function where you shouldn't be (which is not advice I can imagine the book containing). Every call to `getchar` tries to get and return, the **next** available character. So `(ch = getchar()) != ' ' && (ch = getchar()) != '\n'` tries to get two different characters, comparing the first to `' '` and the second to `'\n'`.

Comment: Kudos for not using `char` to store result of `getchar`. But `long` is a bit oversized.

Comment: Your task is to read one character and decide whether to print it or not. That second condition reads up to 4 characters and only prints one.

Comment: Think about what your code is doing.  Look at this expression:  `(ch = getchar()) != ' ' && (ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ...)`  What if the first character read is `'a'`?  Then the first comparison succeeds, so it proceeds to the next operand of `&&`, which immediately reads a new character, replacing the value of `ch`.  Now the `'a'` has been lost, never to be recovered.  Bug.  So, don't do that.  Only call `getchar()` when you want to read the next character (and are done with the current character).

Comment: Thank you very much all! Your answers were much clarifying.

Comment: I do have a K&R lying around and I don't seem to find any such advice on page 17.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI: it is not on page 17 of the second edition, nor of the *C Answer Book* although exercise 1-12 is given an solution on page 16 of this book.  The OP might be using the first edition (a collector item) or a pdf scan with missing pages.

Comment: In K&R 2nd Edition, exercise 1-12 on p21 is "Write a program that prints its input one word per line".  In K&R 1st Edition, that's exercise 1-11 on p19.  I don't see anything in either edition that suggests that `getchar()` should be called multiple times in a single line.  The section "Character counting" starts on p17 in 2nd; it starts on p15 in 1st.  I still see nothing that suggests calling `getchar()` multiple times as shown in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some remarks regarding the code you posted:

> **Exercise 1-12.** Write a program that prints its input one word per line.

- the type of `ch` should be `int`, not `long`.
- the test in the `while` loop is redundant for the first iteration as `ch` is guaranteed to be different from space, TAB, newline and `EOF`. You could use a `do` / `while` loop, although  I would recommend abstaining:

  ```
      if (ch != ' ' && ch != '\n' && ch != '\t') {
          do {
              putchar(ch);
              ch = getchar();
          } while (ch != EOF & ch != ' ' && ch != '\n' && ch != '\t') {
          putchar('\n');
      }
  ```

The modified version does not work because the loop reads more characters instead of testing the current character read from `stdin`:

```
while ((ch = getchar()) != ' ' && (ch = getchar()) != '\n' && (ch = getchar()) != '\t' && (ch = getchar()) != EOF)
```

Is evaluated according to these steps:

- `ch = getchar()` reads a new byte from the stream, overwriting the current one which will never be printed.
- `(ch = getchar()) != ' '` compares the newly read byte with `' '` and unless it is a space, the next test will evaluate...
- `&& (ch = getchar()) != '\n'` reads yet another byte and compares it to `'\n'`. The first and second bytes have been lost and if the third is not a newline, we keep going...
- `&& (ch = getchar()) != '\t'` reads yet another byte and compares it to `'\t'`. The first, second and third bytes have been lost and if the fourth is not a TAB, we keep going...
- `&& (ch = getchar()) != EOF` reads yet another byte and compares it to `EOF`. The first, second, third and fourth bytes have been lost and if the fifth is not `EOF`, we finally print it and iterate after reading another byte which will be lost immediately as the `while` test is evaluated again.

The net effect is every fifth byte is output on average and most of the words output (not necessarily one per line) are incorrect.

To avoid reading more than one byte from the stream per iteration, you could use a state to determine what to do depending on whether the byte is a space or not:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int ch;
    int inword = 0;

    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (ch == ' ' || ch == '\n' || ch == '\t') {
            if (inword) {
                /* this is the end of the word (pun intended) */
                putchar('\n');
                inword = 0;
            }
        } else {
            putchar(ch);
            inword = 1;
        }
    }
    if (inword) {
        /* the last word in the input stream is not followed by a blank nor a newline) */
        putchar('\n');
    }
    return 0;
}
```